# Python-RPy - "Error in x$terms : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: python, r

I am new in RPy, so excuse me, if my question is trivial. I'm trying to write the top solution from this topic: [Screening (multi)collinearity in a regression model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042117/screening-multicollinearity-in-a-regression-model) in Python, but I get following error:

> rpy.RPy_RException: Error in x$terms : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Code I wrote:

```
from rpy import *
r.set_seed(42)
a=r.rnorm(100)
b=r.rnorm(100)
m=r.model_matrix('~a+b')
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
using reply written by agstudy (thank You for help!) I prepared solution working for rpy2

```
from rpy2 import robjects
rset_seed = robjects.r('set.seed')
fmla = robjects.Formula('~a+b')
model_matrix = robjects.r('model.matrix')
rnorm = robjects.r('rnorm')
rset_seed(42)
env = fmla.environment
env['a']=rnorm(100)
env['b']=rnorm(100)
m=model_matrix(fmla)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
fmla = r.Formula('~a+b')
env = fmla.environment
env['a'] = a
env['b'] = b
r.model_matrix(fmla)
```

In R, you can reproduce the error

```
set_seed(42)
a=rnorm(100)
b=rnorm(100)
m=model.matrix('~a+b')
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
m=model.matrix(formula('~a+b')) ## this works
  (Intercept)          a          b
1           1 -0.1011361  0.4354445
2           1  0.3782215 -1.5322641
3           1  1.4772023  0.3280948
4           1  0.2892421  1.9012016
5           1 -0.2596562  0.2036678
6           1 -0.5585396 -0.1536021
```

Comment: How about `m=model.matrix(~a+b)` ?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg thanks. This works in R of course. But what about rpy/rpy2?

Comment: I checked 'm=r.model_matrix(r.formula("~a+b"))' in rpy, but I get following error: 'rpy.RPy_RException: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object "a" not found'

Comment: @user1633361 I update my answer. I don't have a rpy Console to test my  answer. I essentially give you the idea.