# Capturing high multi-collinearity in statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, statsmodels

Say I fit a model in statsmodels

```
mod = smf.ols('dependent ~ first_category + second_category + other', data=df).fit()
```

When I do `mod.summary()` I may see the following:

```
Warnings:
[1] The condition number is large, 1.59e+05. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.
```

Sometimes the warning is different (e.g. based on eigenvalues of the design matrix). How can I capture **high-multi-collinearity** conditions in a variable? Is this warning stored somewhere in the model object?

Also, where can I find a description of the fields in `summary()`?

Comment: [Good News](https://machinelearningmind.com/2019/10/19/multicollinearity-how-to-fix-it/) is that "Multicollinearity only affects the coefficients and p-values, but it does not influence the model’s ability to predict the dependent variable" (I hope, it's true)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can detect high-multi-collinearity by inspecting the *eigen values* of *correlation matrix*. A very low eigen value shows that the data are collinear, and the corresponding *eigen vector* shows which variables are collinear.

If there is no collinearity in the data, you would expect that none of the eigen values are close to zero:

```
>>> xs = np.random.randn(100, 5)      # independent variables
>>> corr = np.corrcoef(xs, rowvar=0)  # correlation matrix
>>> w, v = np.linalg.eig(corr)        # eigen values & eigen vectors
>>> w
array([ 1.256 ,  1.1937,  0.7273,  0.9516,  0.8714])
```

However, if say `x[4] - 2 * x[0] - 3 * x[2] = 0`, then

```
>>> noise = np.random.randn(100)                      # white noise
>>> xs[:,4] = 2 * xs[:,0] + 3 * xs[:,2] + .5 * noise  # collinearity
>>> corr = np.corrcoef(xs, rowvar=0)
>>> w, v = np.linalg.eig(corr)
>>> w
array([ 0.0083,  1.9569,  1.1687,  0.8681,  0.9981])
```

one of the eigen values (here the very first one), is close to zero. The corresponding eigen vector is:

```
>>> v[:,0]
array([-0.4077,  0.0059, -0.5886,  0.0018,  0.6981])
```

Ignoring *almost zero* coefficients, above basically says `x[0]`, `x[2]` and `x[4]` are colinear (as expected). If one standardizes `xs` values and multiplies by this eigen vector, the result will hover around zero with small variance:

```
>>> std_xs = (xs - xs.mean(axis=0)) / xs.std(axis=0)  # standardized values
>>> ys = std_xs.dot(v[:,0])
>>> ys.mean(), ys.var()
(0, 0.0083)
```

Note that `ys.var()` is basically the eigen value which was close to zero.

So, in order to capture high multi-linearity, look at the eigen values of correlation matrix.

Comment: Thanks. This approach [isn't mentioned in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). Would you mind explaining, or do you know of any sources that explain why small eigen values of the correlation matrix are indicative of multi-collinearity?

Comment: @user815423426 the theory is longer than what would fit in here, but look into [`PCA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Basically, each eigen vector explains the variation in the data orthogonal to other eigen vectors, and the eigen value shows how much variation is in that direction. An almost zero eigen value shows a direction with zero variation, hence collinearity.

Comment: I'm confused. eigenvalues close to zero indication collinearity. The first eigenvalue is close to zero so you then inspect the eigen**vectors**. From `[-0.4077,  0.0059, -0.5886,  0.0018,  0.6981]`, you determined `x[0]`, `x[2]` and `x[4]` were colinear. So in the eigenvectors, we're looking for numbers **not** close to zero?

Comment: @Jarad Yes. If `eigenvalues` *are close* to zero, look at their corresponding `eigenvectors` for values that *are not close* to zero and the indices of those values represent the features that are collinear. As a side note, you can also standardize the data first (e.g. using `StandardScaler` in `sklearn`) and use the `np.cov` function (in place of `np.corrcoef`) as well which will return you a covariance matrix (`cov_mat = np.cov(xs_standardized)` and you can perform eigen-decomposition on that in the same manner demonstrated above and follow the same procedure to determine collinear features.

Answer (score 5):

Based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042117/screening-multicollinearity-in-a-regression-model?rq=1) for R, there are some other options that may help people. I was looking for a single number that captured the collinearity, and options include the determinant and condition number of the correlation matrix.

According to one of the R answers, determinant of the correlation matrix will "range from 0 (Perfect Collinearity) to 1 (No Collinearity)". I found the bounded range helpful.

Translated example for determinant:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample random dataframe
np.random.seed(321)
x1 = np.random.rand(100)
x2 = np.random.rand(100)
x3 = np.random.rand(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'x3': x3})

# Now create a dataframe with multicollinearity
multicollinear_df = df.copy()
multicollinear_df['x3'] = multicollinear_df['x1'] + multicollinear_df['x2']

# Compute both correlation matrices
corr = np.corrcoef(df, rowvar=0)
multicollinear_corr = np.corrcoef(multicollinear_df, rowvar=0)

# Compare the determinants
print np.linalg.det(corr) . # 0.988532159861
print np.linalg.det(multicollinear_corr) . # 2.97779797328e-16
```

And similarly, the condition number of the covariance matrix will approach infinity with perfect linear dependence.

```
print np.linalg.cond(corr) . # 1.23116253259
print np.linalg.cond(multicollinear_corr) . # 6.19985218873e+15
```

Comment: ? why `np.linalg.cond` from `corr` ? [here](https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Regression%20Diagnostics.ipynb)  `np.linalg.cond(results.model.exog)` from OLS, where  x is [exogenous](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/endog_exog.html) to the model