# Linear regression in R and Python - Different results at same problem

Tags: python, r, statistics, linear-regression, data-science

I am training my data skills in python which I have learned in R. Although, I have a doubt about a simple linear regression

Climate_change Data:
[[link here]](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/f43727842620758fda4e204cc0d7d558/asset-v1:MITx+15.071x+3T2018+type@asset+block/climate_change.csv)

## Python Script

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm



train = df[df.Year>=2006]

X = train[['MEI', 'CO2', 'CH4', 'N2O', 'CFC.11', 'CFC.12', 'TSI', 'Aerosols']]
y = train[['Temp']]
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.summary()
```

## Python Result

> Dep. Variable: Temp  R-squared: 0.972
>
> Model: OLS  Adj. R-squared: 0.964
>
> Method: Least Squares  F-statistic: 123.1
>
> Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2018  Prob (F-statistic):9.54e-20
>
> Time: 14:52:53  Log-Likelihood: 46.898
>
> No. Observations: 36  AIC: -77.80
>
> Df Residuals: 28  BIC: -65.13
>
> Df Model: 8
>
> Covariance Type: nonrobust
>
> MEI
>   0.0361
>
> CO2
>   0.0046
>
> CH4
>   -0.0023
>
> N2O
>   -0.0141
>
> CFC-11
>   -0.0312
>
> CFC-12
>   0.0358
>
> TSI
>   -0.0033
>
> Aerosols
>   69.9680
>
> Omnibus:8.397
>   Durbin-Watson: 1.484
>
> Prob(Omnibus):0.015
>   Jarque-Bera (JB):10.511
>
> Skew: -0.546
>   Prob(JB): 0.00522
>
> Kurtosis: 5.412
>   Cond. No. 6.35e+06

## R Script

```
train <- climate_change[climate_change$Year>=2006,]
prev <- lm(Temp ~ ., data = train[,3:NCOL(train)])
summary(prev)
```

## R Result

> Residuals:
>         Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
>   -0.221684 -0.032846  0.002042  0.037158  0.167887
>
> Coefficients:
>   MEI 0.036056
>   CO2 0.004817
>   CH4 -0.002366
>   N2O -0.013007
>   CFC-11 -0.033194
>   CFC-12 0.037775
>   TSI   0.009100
>   Aerosols 70.463329
>   Residual standard error: 0.07594 on 27 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared:  0.5346,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.3967  F-statistic: 3.877 on
>   8 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.003721

## Question

The R-squared has big difference between them, also the coefficients of independent variable has a bit difference. Someone could explain why?

Comment: Do you get any warnngs with `python`.  I am getting `The condition number is large, 6.35e+06. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.`

Comment: Yes, i got the same warning `Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The condition number is large, 6.35e+06. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.`

Comment: It could be due to different implementations.  Please check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116825/different-output-for-r-lm-and-python-statsmodel-ols-for-linear-regression)

Comment: also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676145/capturing-high-multi-collinearity-in-statsmodels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to point this out: `statsmodel`'s least squares fit does by default not include a constant. If we remove the constant from R's fit, we get very similar results to the Python implementation, or the other way around, if we add a constant to the `statsmodel`-fit, we get similar results to `R`:

Remove the constant in `R`'s `lm`-call:

```
summary(lm(Temp ~ . - 1, data = train[,3:NCOL(train)]))

Call:
lm(formula = Temp ~ . - 1, data = train[, 3:NCOL(train)])

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.221940 -0.032347  0.002071  0.037048  0.167294 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
MEI       0.036076   0.027983   1.289   0.2079  
CO2       0.004640   0.008945   0.519   0.6080  
CH4      -0.002328   0.002132  -1.092   0.2843  
N2O      -0.014115   0.079452  -0.178   0.8603  
`CFC-11` -0.031232   0.096693  -0.323   0.7491  
`CFC-12`  0.035760   0.103574   0.345   0.7325  
TSI      -0.003283   0.036861  -0.089   0.9297  
Aerosols 69.968040  33.093275   2.114   0.0435 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.07457 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9724,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9645 
F-statistic: 123.1 on 8 and 28 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Let's add a constant to `statsmodel`'s call:

```
X_with_constant = sm.add_constant(X)

model = sm.OLS(y, X_with_constant).fit()
model.summary()
```

gives us identical results:

```
OLS Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  Temp    R-squared:  0.535
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: 0.397
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    3.877
Date:   Tue, 02 Oct 2018    Prob (F-statistic): 0.00372
Time:   10:14:03    Log-Likelihood: 46.899
No. Observations:   36  AIC:    -75.80
Df Residuals:   27  BIC:    -61.55
Df Model:   8       
Covariance Type:    nonrobust       
coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
const   -17.8663    563.008 -0.032  0.975   -1173.064   1137.332
MEI 0.0361  0.029   1.265   0.217   -0.022  0.095
CO2 0.0048  0.011   0.451   0.656   -0.017  0.027
CH4 -0.0024 0.002   -0.950  0.351   -0.007  0.003
N2O -0.0130 0.088   -0.148  0.884   -0.194  0.168
CFC-11  -0.0332 0.116   -0.285  0.777   -0.272  0.205
CFC-12  0.0378  0.123   0.307   0.761   -0.215  0.290
TSI 0.0091  0.392   0.023   0.982   -0.795  0.813
Aerosols    70.4633 37.139  1.897   0.069   -5.739  146.666
Omnibus:    8.316   Durbin-Watson:  1.488
Prob(Omnibus):  0.016   Jarque-Bera (JB):   10.432
Skew:   -0.535  Prob(JB):   0.00543
Kurtosis:   5.410   Cond. No.   1.06e+08
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it could be an issue with multicollinearity based on the warnings given.  One way to test whether we get the same r-squared is by using another package `sklearn` and build the model based on the `LinearRegression` module

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)
predictions = regr.predict(X)
r2_score(y, predictions)
#0.5345800653144226
```

But, `LinearRegression` wouldn't give any `summary` output.  Have to extract the parameters of interest