# clustered standard errors in statsmodel with multicolinearity problem

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using statsmodel for OLS regression. When I clustered the standard error, there was this warning message indicating multicolinearity issue. However, if I just fit the model **without clustered errors**, there is no such warning.

```
mod = smf.ols(formula = var ~ treatment_r1 + block + has_multiple_treat', data = df)
mod_res = mod.fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['block']}, use_t=True)



ValueWarning: covariance of constraints does not have full rank. The number of constraints is 3, but rank is 1
      'rank is %d' % (J, J_), ValueWarning)
```

I checked co-linearity following this post [Capturing high multi-collinearity in statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676145/capturing-high-multi-collinearity-in-statsmodels) and didn't find any problem.

```
corr = np.corrcoef(df_new[["var", "has_multiple_treat", "treatment_r1", "block1"]], rowvar=0)
w, v = np.linalg.eig(corr)
w
np.linalg.det(corr)
```

The *var* can be a 0 or 1 variable or a continuous variable; *treatment_r1*, *has_multiple_treat* is a 0 or 1 variable; *block* is a categorical variable with two categories and in the df_new dataframe, I turned *block* into a dummy variable (*block1* and *block2*) and dropped block2.

Comment: Where is the value error raised? Full or at least end of traceback or a replicable example. AFAIR, there is no such warning in the `cov_type` code. There can be a problem with singular matrix in cluster robust cov_params if there are too few clusters relative to within cluster size.

Comment: If your `groups` variable "block" has only two clusters, then cluster robust doesn't work, and you need to assume more structure on the within cluster correlation.

Comment: Have you figured out the reason behind the warning? I got the same warning. Thanks.